# Creating shared_ptr seems to cause segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I have the following function

```
static node_ptr make_node_ptr()
{
  return node_ptr(new node());
}
```

where `using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<node>;`

I tried to find my segmentation fault with valgrind and gdb. In both I get more or less the same stack trace.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff8f5d7e82 in szone_malloc_should_clear () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8f5d7e82 in szone_malloc_should_clear () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
#1  0x00007fff8f5d7877 in malloc_zone_malloc () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
#2  0x00007fff8f5d6395 in malloc () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
#3  0x00000001000f17d8 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libstdc++.6.dylib
#4  0x0000000100009c04 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node*> (this=0x7fff5f4002e8, __p=0x10059ffc0)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:569
#5  0x0000000100008c78 in std::__shared_ptr<msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node> (this=0x7fff5f4002e0, __p=0x10059ffc0)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:871
#6  0x00000001000079e5 in std::shared_ptr<msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node>::shared_ptr<msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node> (this=0x7fff5f4002e0, __p=0x10059ffc0)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:113
#7  0x0000000100005bdc in msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::make_node_ptr () at ../../common/msc/scene.d/scene_manager_def.h:98
#8  0x00000001000037dd in msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node::generate_wrapping_node (wrappee=...) at ../../common/msc/scene.d/node_impl.h:73
#9  0x0000000100003d53 in msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::node::generate_wrapping_node (nodes=...) at ../../common/msc/scene.d/node_impl.h:112
#10 0x0000000100004011 in msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::insert (this=0x7fff5f82ee90, root=..., other=...) at ../../common/msc/scene.d/scene_manager_impl.h:97
#11 0x0000000100006071 in msc::scene_manager<float, int, 3ul>::insert_if_leq (this=0x7fff5f82ee90, root=..., other=...) at ../../common/msc/scene.d/scene_manager_impl.h:127
```

The last 2 lines repeat endlessly, I guess at least, as I tried to continue until frame #6000 or smth.

Am I missing something or is the creation of this shared_ptr not allowed?

**Edit**

```
node_ptr scene_manager::insert(node_ptr & root, node_ptr other)
{
  bool swapped = false;

  if (root == nullptr)
    root = other;
  else
  {
    auto inside = msc::inside::test(*root, *other);
    if (inside == msc::inside::NONE)
    {
      auto oldRoot = root;
      root = node::generate_wrapping_node(
        std::vector<node_c_ptr>{ oldRoot, other });
      insert_if_leq(root, oldRoot);
    }
    else if ((swapped = (inside == msc::inside::FIRST)))
    {
      std::swap(root, other);
    }
    other = insert_if_leq(root, other);
  }

  return !swapped ? other : root;
}

node_ptr scene_manager::insert_if_leq(node_ptr root, node_ptr other)
{
  node_ptr res = root;

  if (are_similar(*root, *other))
    msc::move_append(root->children, other->children);
  else
  {
    auto idx = root->get_quadrant_idx(other->center);
    res = insert(root->quadrants[idx], other);
  }

  return res;
}
```

These are the functions which repeat. `msc` is my own namespace.

Comment: Can you show your constructor for `node`?

Comment: The code you showed has nothing wrong with it. Does your system involve plugins/dylibs loaded dynamically? You might run into these kinds of issues on shutdown if your `shared_ptr` is pointing to destruction code inside a plugin that has already been unloaded. Also is `make_node_ptr` used in a way that captures a file-scope static? You have to be careful with the way `shared_ptr` prolongs object lifetimes, possibly to where they only get destroyed outside of `main` (possibly a point that is too late to properly destroy the object).

Comment: Also your function could just be `return std::make_shared<node>();`

Comment: @Ike: I have quite much code, but except for the standard library I do not use any other code. @Cyber: And this is the code for node.
`node() : children(), quadrants(), parent() { quadrants.fill(nullptr); }`

Comment: What's at the very bottom of your stack trace? Is there an exit call involved and outside of `main`? Useful here is showing the stack in its entirety, the origin from which `make_node_ptr` is called, and the constructor and destructor logic of your nodes (and possibly scene graph).

Comment: Also does your segfault happen at shutdown or in the middle of execution?

Comment: @Ike: I added some of the stacktrace, but as the last two lines repeat infinitely I cannot post the full stacktrace. And it happens in the middle of the execution.

Comment: @satanik The problem is not the shared pointer, but somewhere inside the ctor or deeper still. Basically it's in those last two lines that cause the loop, look at `insert` and `insert_if_leq`. Or show us those functions. :)

Comment: Oh I see, so there's some kind of recursion going on there between `insert_if_leq` and `insert`? Is your scene graph actually supposed to be like 3000+ levels deep? As Daniel wisely suggested, showing the logic of these two functions would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Can I post so much Code? Sorry for the question.

Comment: @Ike: Yes there is a recursion, but it should not repeat that often and it certainly does not. I think it is no endless recursion as the code executed afterwards exists. Am I right?

Comment: @satanik Better yet: Take your code and **reduce** it to the smallest example that still shows your problem. Most often you will find yourself finding the problem in the process, otherwise you have created a small piece of code that others are (most likely) happy to look at and help. This is a very valuable skill!

Comment: Yeah, it just seems to me like your scene graph is insanely deep, but it does seem to finish and actually get to the node creation. Nevertheless, if you have a case where your call stack goes off seemingly ad-infinitum, I'd look at the logic involved in the recursion.

Comment: @Ike: When I think about it it actually can be 3000 levels deep, but only the calls. Because I insert only 40 elements in the scenegraph. But the elements are inserted in boundingboxes which just wrap around the elements. So no unnecessary nodes are created

Comment: In that case, while it may not address your immediate issue, I would look at creating a non-recursive solution of these functions. If you _can_ legimitately recurse 6000+ levels deep in the call stack with just 40 scene graph elements, that logic needs to be revisited, and getting a non-recursive version for a start should make that call graph digestible and make the issue a bit more obvious if nothing else. There's a safety hazard there in utilizing recursion when it can reach such depths.

Comment: @satanik Not really, as this is not a complete example we can fully understand. Check out the help center's description of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DanielFrey: I understand that. But I do not think I can create the problem with much less code as I already did in my class.

Comment: @satanik In that case I'm sorry, but I can't provide any immediate solution. From the looks of your code there is lots of room for improvement, though. In general, those member functions should not have more than 3 lines and each method should have a very dedicated functionality. Maybe try refactoring your code to improve the general quality and most of the current complexity in the too long and complicated algorithms goes away. But that is just my gut feeling. Good luck!

Comment: @DanielFrey: I will try. Thx nontheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the functions are recursive `insert` calls `insert_if_leq` and vice versa, I had to make `node_ptr root` in `insert_if_leq` a reference, because the assignment in `insert` depended on it. The new function definitions are as follows:

`node_ptr scene_manager::insert(node_ptr & root, node_ptr other)`

`node_ptr scene_manager::insert_if_leq(node_ptr & root, node_ptr other)`